# Set Progress to UITableViewCell element

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have an UITableViewCell with custom UIView with progress bar. By clicking on cell app starts to load some content from API with Alamofire. I know how to get current downloaded progress and how to pass it to progress view but I'm using RxSwift+Realm and when I'm scrolling UITableView cell's progress not showing. I want to show progress even when I'm scrolling UITableView. I've tried to store progress in cell's Realm element variable and subscribed to this variable in cell, but this action loads MainTread.

This is dataSource for my UITableView

```
let tableData: Observable<[Song]> = Observable.combineLatest(loadedData.asObservable(), dbData.asObservable()) { (loadedData, dbData) -> [Song] in
        var newArray = self.currentPlaylist == nil ? loadedData.filter({ !$0.isInvalidated }) : dbData.filter({ !$0.isInvalidated && self.currentPlaylist!.plSongs.contains($0) })

        if self.currentPlaylist == nil {
            _ = dbData.filter({ !$0.isInvalidated }).map({ data in
                if newArray.contains(where: { $0.compoundKey == data.compoundKey && !data.isInvalidated }) {
                    newArray[newArray.index(where: {$0.compoundKey == data.compoundKey && !data.isInvalidated })!] = data
                }
            })
        }
        return newArray.filter({ !$0.isInvalidated })
    }

    tableData
        .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "SongCell", cellType: SongTableViewCell.self)) { (_, element, cell) in
            cell.songResponse = element

            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

This is UITableView Cell

```
var songLoadedProgress = Variable<Float?>(nil)
var songResponse: Song? {
    didSet {
        self.layoutCell()
    }
}

func layoutCell() {
    songLoadedProgress.value = songResponse?.songLoadedProgress

            songLoadedProgress.asObservable()
        .bind { (progress) in
            guard let loadingProgress = progress else { return }
            self.downloadView.circleView.setProgress(value: CGFloat(loadingProgress), animationDuration: 0.1)
        }
        .disposed(by: cellBag)
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: you should move the API call to the VC, maybe in an operation queue with a delegate or something, then configure the cell on willDisplayCell, with the progress and delegate for updates.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLintern88. You should, first of all, move api call to your view controller!